# Adding a hover event to a UI.Toggle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I know that to dynamically add a "hover" effect to a button you need a script that implements `IPointerEnterHandler` and `IPointerExitHandler`, perfect, great, my buttons can have hovers now.

However, when I attempt to do the same thing for a `Toggle` the event handler code doesn't execute. E.g. if I have this:

```
public class TooltipTrigger : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler {

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData) {
        Debug.Log("Pointer entered");
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData) {
        Debug.Log("Pointer exited");
    }
}
```

And attach it to the same GameObject that has a `Toggle` component, those debug statements never run. But if I attach it to a GameObject with a `Button` component, it does.

And I checked [`UI.Toggle Inherits from:UI.Selectable`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Toggle.html), same as a button does. This *should work.*

Comment: Weird. Can you check/show us the editor view of the GameObject with the `Toggle` on it?

Comment: @IanH. I just figured out that I'm an idiot. I was script-attaching the (above) component to a completely different toggle object...

Comment: Beautiful, glad it works for you now! :)
I would suggest that you answer your question with your solution, rather than deleting it, so people that find this question may double check if they have the same problem. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was inadvertently targeting the wrong toggle with the script that was attaching the `TooltipTrigger` script to the toggle.